# Placement of data files for java web service

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

I am writing a simple web service on java, that should read an xml file and generate a string for result. I am, however, at loss as to:

a) where should xml file be placed in the file system for it to be accessible to web service?

b) what would the relative way to the file from the service

c) alternatelyt, how can i add xml file to the project, so that it would be deployed along with web service

I am using NetBeans as IDE and maven as a build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I provide a resource-bundle (.jar) in my web application. If the file should not be modified during runtime, this should be the best way to access it. This will be c) in your question. There you can access the file with:

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream("resourceName");
```

`"resourceName"` will be the path inside the jar file. I you are packaging with Maven, everything in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes` will be available in your classpath and can be loaded with `getResourceAsStream`.

---

An alternative way with maven is to create a new module and place all required resources in `src/main/resources` and then add a dependency to this artifact in your webapp pom.

Comment: /WEB-INF isn't in CLASSPATH, but /WEB-INF/classes is.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what resource-bundle IS and how exactly you provide it? A link to tutorial would be sufficient.

Comment: So, if i place my file 'filename.xml' in WEB-INF, and then call getResourceAsStream("filename.xml"), i'll access it? Trying now

Comment: @Srv10 It must be in WEB-INF/classes, see the correction from duffymo.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I have no idea if i would've figured that out if not for you - and when

Answer (score 0):

a) Anywhere, as long as your process has permissions to access the file.

b) The relative path depend on the App server you are using. The relative path is relative to the home of the jvm. for *tomcat* is is *tomacat-base*, for *weblogic* is the *domain directory*. I would recommend to do not depend on this, but have configuration param that contains the absolute path.

c) put it in WEB-INF (servletcontext path) or WEB-INF/classes (you can access it as classpath resource)